# Sequelize bulkCreate updateOnDuplicate update only selected columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

What I am trying to achieve here is that i have a table ProfileMasters with N number of columns, however only 5-6 of those are frequently updated and we want to update those data in bulk and actually we don't want to insert if there is no `id` matching in the table (couldn't find solution for this)

Hence I came up with the below statement

```
await ProfileMaster.bulkCreate(itemsForMaster, {updateOnDuplicate: ['id']})
```

The problem here is the `itemsForMaster` sends only 5-6 columns that we need to update including the id.

The query generated is below

```
INSERT INTO `ProfileMasters` (`id`, `type`, `alias`, `reference`, `also_known_as`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`)
        VALUES(3, 'profile', 'Liver Profile, LFT, liver test', '', '', '2022-09-21 05:37:48', '2022-09-21 05:37:48') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = VALUES(`id`);
```

However this doesn't update anything.

Can you please suggest what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't need to use `bulkCreate` at all because you don't want to insert new records. Unfortunately, there is not such method as `bulkUpdate` and RDMSes usually don't have bulk `UPDATE` SQL statements unlike `INSERT` ones.
So all in all you need to loop though `itemsForMaster` and call `update` for each item:

```js
for (const item of itemsForMaster) {
  const { id, ...fieldsToUpdate } = item;
  await ProfileMaster.update(fieldsToUpdate. { id })
}
```

Comment: Collect promises in an array and could be used `await Promise.all(promises)` if any error occurred while updating.

Comment: It depends on amount of items, It wouldn't be wise to run hundreds of queries in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` that you pass to `updateOnDuplicate` is the columns that you want to be updated. So you just pass `id` and it always updates just the `id`